# Calling child component async function in parent is not working

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component, supabase

I have a Child component where I check if user is logged in:

```
    <script>
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

import { user } from '../sessionStore';
import { supabase } from '../supabaseClient';
import Dashboard from './dashboard.svelte';
import Signin from './signin.svelte';

let loading = false;

async function isLogged() {
    try {
        loading = true;
        const user = supabase.auth.user();

        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_, session) => {
            user.set(session.user);
        });

        let { data, error, status } = await supabase
            .from('users')
            .select('*')
            .eq('id', user.id)
            .single();

        if (error && status !== 406) throw error;

        if (data) {
            goto('/signin');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        goto('/signin');
    } finally {
        loading = false;
    }
}
<p use:isLogged></p>
```

If I go to this page directly it works but when I call this component in my other pages its not working,
in my dashboard I call this component simply by importing it and inserting it in the page:

```
<Child/>
```

How can I make this work?
Please let me know!

Comment: I think this question is missing some information but let's see if I can help with what you have provided. Is this Child component used in multiple pages? if yes this probably won't work since you should only have one `onAuthStateChange` in your project and in the case where this is an SPA it would mean you have multiple if the component is used in different pages.

Comment: @AndrewSmith yes Child is used in multiple components,could you please help me with some suggestions how to handle this check weather the users is logged in or not?

Comment: Move it to the root __layout.svelte file instead.